# Applescript to trigger Time Machine in Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: operating-system, applescript, osx-mavericks, timemachine

I've used the following bit of Applescript for years to trigger Time Machine from within an Applescript. It no longer seems to work in Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks. Anyone know of a solution or alternative. This script runs and does not throw any error messages. It simply does nothing.

```
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd-helper >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use tmutil in 10.7 and later:

```
do shell script "tmutil startbackup"
```

`-b` blocks the script until saving the snapshot has finished, so you can do something like `tmutil startbackup -b&&diskutil eject Time\ Machine`. `-a` performs the backup in a mode similar to automatically scheduled backups.

```
startbackup [-a | --auto] [-b | --block] [-r | --rotation] [-d |
        --destination dest_id]
        Begin a backup if one is not already running.

        Options:
            --auto           Run the backup in a mode similar to system-
                             scheduled backups.
            --block          Wait (block) until the backup is finished
                             before exiting.
            --rotation       Allow automatic destination rotation during
                             the backup.
            --destination    Perform the backup to the destination corre-
                             sponding to the specified ID.

        The --auto option provides a supported mechanism with which to
        trigger "automatic-like" backups, similar to automatic backups
        that are scheduled by the system. While this is not identical to
        true system-scheduled backups, it provides custom schedulers the
        ability to achieve some (but not all) behavior normally exhibited
        when operating in automatic mode.
```

Comment: At least in macOS High Sierra you need administrator privileges for `tmutil`. So the line would be: `do shell script "tmutil startbackup" with administrator privileges` – you will be prompt to enter username and password.